# ios fileExistsAtPath failing for new file

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I am writing a file, then adding the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to the file.  To do this I have the following two methods in my HPSFileHelper class:

```
+(void)writeDataToFileWithData:(NSData*)data andFilename:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    [HPSFileHelper addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:fileURL]; // Prevent this file from being backed up.
}

+(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;

}
```

The problem is that the assert ... fileExistsAtPath is failing occasionally.  Presumably this is because sometimes a file has not been fully written and unlocked by the time the assert runs? (for large files?)

How should I code around this issue?

Comment: Well the assert is set to make sure that the fileExists so presumably the file does not exist and is failing(could be because of not fully written, although I'm not sure). assert is for debugging purposes, what you really should be concerned with is why is  `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:` being called on that path before it is created. Also check that the paths you're setting up are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsequent investigation reveals that writeToFile is synchronous, and the file WILL have been written by the time the method returns.

The issue was caused by encountering an auto-generated filename that contained a slash char '/'.  This meant the file creation failed.  I have now changed the writeToFile;atomically to:

```
BOOL bWorked = [data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&errorPtr];

if (!bWorked)
{
    NSLog(@"writeDataToFileWithData failed for %@ %@", filePath,errorPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is probably to use `NO` for the `atomically:` parameter of `writeToFile:atomically:` method.

- Writing a file *atomically*  means that the system writes the file content in a temporary file, and once it has written it all, move the file to the final path.
  *(This is designed to make sure that in case of a failure during writing the file for example, the final path does not contain unfinished file content)*
- Using `NO` for this parameter will make the system writing the file directly to its final destination/path (instead of using a temporary file and then move it).

So my guess is that when using `atomically:YES` and thus using a temporary file, by the time you call `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:` the system may not have finished to write the temporary file (and thus didn't even start to move it to its final path/destination) and it explains why your assert fails.

Whereas using `atomically:NO`, the system will already at least have started to write to the final path when you call `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:` and your assert should hopefully then not fail.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs on `writeToFile:atomically:`:

> *atomically*
>
> If YES, the data is written to a backup file, and then—assuming no errors occur—the backup file is renamed to the name specified by path; otherwise, the data is written directly to path.

Just a hypothesis, but when you call `[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`, your call could return when the temporary file is finished being written but the renaming hasn't yet occurred, in which case `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]` would return NO.

My hunch is that if you switched your call to `[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO]`, this bug would go away.